# Proof of Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm analysing proof of Schwarz lemma that is presented here on page 4:

http://www.dm.unipi.it/~abate/libri/libriric/files/IterationThTautMan1-1.pdf

I don't understand, why author claims that function $g$ is holomorphic on whole disk (ie. at $0$). Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(0) = 0$, the function $g(z) = f(z)/z$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. We may as well consider $g$ as holomorphic on the whole disc.